# Object rotates on a different axis

Tags: animation, transforms

I recently made a Knife. I got stuck. Whenever I try to rotate that knife along Y axis through transformation panel, it get rotated along X axis. Same when doing along X axis,it rotate along z axis. But Z-axis rotation is fine. I ensured XYZ 
euler. Tried Global to Local. Need Helpp..

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl-A to *Apply Rotation and Scale*?  If so, can you provide a screenshot or two of your editor?

Comment: Try rotating with interactive R command, use X,Y,Z to visually set the rotation axis. Pressing twice changes axis scope (eg: global, local)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use The Hotkey Instead Of the transformation panel Which Is **(R)** Button In The Keyboard To Rotate ,And Choose On Your Keyboard The Axis You Want To Rotate Around **(X)** or **(Y)** and **(Z)** 
And Type Your Rotation Angle Or Move Your Mouse.

Comment: I did that but this makes animation wrong. I insert key frame with rotation only along y axis but in animation it also rotates along x axis.